# How Test MapGetter

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuex

I would like to test if my getter is called in my component or view, but I don't understand how can it.

My method in the component :

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({ item: 'moduleA/getData' }),
},
```

And this is my unit test declaration :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    store = new Vuex.Store({
      modules: {
        moduleA: {
          state: {},
          getters: {
            getData() {
              return { item: { name: 'test' } };
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
    wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      store,
    });
  });
```

And I try to test if the data is loaded in my template:

```
it('should check if name is thruthy', () => {
  expect(wrapper.find('.classA').text()).toEqual('test');
});
```

my component :

```
<template>
  <v-content>
    <ComponentA v-if="item.name"
    key="keyA" ></ComponentA>
    <ComponentB v-else key="keyA"></ComponentB>
  </v-content>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import ComponentA from '@/components/ComponentA.vue';
import ComponentB from '@/components/ComponentB.vue';

export default {
  /**
   * Component's name :
   */
  name: 'ViewA',
  /**
   * Component's used :
   */
  components: {
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB,
  },
  /**
   * computed's used :
   */
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ item: 'moduleA/getData' }),
  },
};
</script>
```

and my getter in the moduleA :

```
const getters = {
  getData: state => state.data,
};
```

But I have this message:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Why? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in docs, [`shallowMount`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#shallowmount)'s options has field named `localVue`. To solve your problem you should create a `localVue`, using [`createLocalVue`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#createlocalvue) and pass it to `shallowMount`.

> `createLocalVue` returns a Vue class for you to add components, mixins
>   and install plugins without polluting the global Vue class.

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'

beforeEach(() => {
  const localVue = createLocalVue()

  localVue.use(Vuex)

  store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      moduleA: {
        state: {},
        getters: {
          getData() {
            return { item: { name: 'test' } }
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })

  wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    localVue,
    store,
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I added createlocalvue but i have the same error message.

Comment: Can you share your component's code? Also try to add `namespaced: true` to your module.

Comment: `...mapGetters("moduleA", { item: 'GetterA' })`

Comment: @coco62, same error? Can you provide your code on GitHub?

Comment: Sorry I can't to put on github because it's a professional project... I try again. I changed the v-if in my template and the mock in the describe. Ihave this error message now : did not return .classA, cannot call html() on empty Wrapper